# SAXParser returns wrong characters

Tags: java, saxparser

I currently analyze an issue where an additionally character appears in the data provided by the `characters()` method called from SAXParser. This happens on a huge file (> 800MB) and the data in the element is a large JSON object (> 40k). Slightly modifications make the issue disappear. I found no way to reduce the file and keep the issue reproduceable.

My final idea was to reduce the file to only one element and add a comment with different length. Here is the resulting class that shows the issue happening on some comment lengths:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class MySaxParser {

    public static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        int commentLen;
        MyHandler(int i) {
            commentLen = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            //
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
            if (sb.toString().contains("YYYYYYYY")) {
                if (first && commentLen == 0) {
                    System.out.println("First line is expected data, the other lines are wrong:");
                    System.out.print("Length: " + sb.toString().trim().length() + " ");
                    System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
                    first = false;
                }
                if (sb.toString().trim().length() != 19687) {
                    System.out.print(commentLen + " ");
                    System.out.print("Length: " + sb.toString().trim().length() + " ");
                    System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
                }
            }
            sb.setLength(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
            //
            sb.append(ch, start, length);
        }
    }

    final static String input = //"<?xml version=\"1.1\" encoding=\"UTF-16\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
            "<?xml version=\"1.1\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n" +
            "<xmi:XMI xmi:version=\"2.1\" xmlns:xmi=\"http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n"
            + "<!-- AAA -->"
            + "<data>{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":0,\"XX\":\"XX2778\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":1,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":5,\"X\":3,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":22},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":2,\"XXX\":\"XX.*\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":3,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":4,\"XXX\":\"*\"}}]},{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":6,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":10,\"X\":4,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":4,\"XX\":21},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":7,\"XXX\":\"X.*\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":8,\"XXX\":\"X\"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":9,\"XXX\":\"*\"}}]}],\"XX\":\"X\",\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":11,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":444,\"X\":3,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":79,\"XX\":2},\"XX\":\"X_XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":12,\"XX\":\"XX_45318\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":13,\"X\":3,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":79,\"XX\":2},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":14,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":15,\"XX\":\"XX_45319\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":418,\"X\":6,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":71,\"XX\":2},\"XXX\":\"X_XX___X_XX_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":16,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":17,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":18,\"X\":7,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":102},\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":XX}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":19,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":38,\"X\":7,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":102},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":20,\"X\":18,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":37},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":21,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":17},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":22,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":36,\"X\":7,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":102},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":35,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":23,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":24,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":25,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":26},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"X_XX - X XX_X_XX_XX\"}},{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":27,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":28,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":34,\"X\":7,\"XX\":74,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":101},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":33,\"XXX\":\"X\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":29,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":30,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":31,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":32},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}}]}}]}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":39,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":40,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":41,\"X\":8,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":40},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":XX}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":42,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":51,\"X\":8,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":40},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":43,\"X\":41,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":50},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":44,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":40},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":45,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":49,\"X\":8,\"XX\":17,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":40},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":48,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":46,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":47,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":17}}]}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":52,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":53,\"XX\":\"XX_45320\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":135,\"X\":9,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":20,\"XX\":4},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":54,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":XX,\"X\":XX}],\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":55,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":63,\"X\":10,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":11,\"XX\":6},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":56,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":58,\"X\":10,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":10,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":62},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":57,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":54},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":59,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":60,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":61},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":64,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":65,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":66,\"X\":11,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":11,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":67,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":68,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":69},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":70,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":78,\"X\":12,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":13,\"XX\":6},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":71,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":73,\"X\":12,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":12,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":77},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":72,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":54},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":74,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":75,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":76},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"X\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":79,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":80,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":81,\"X\":13,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":13,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":82,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":83,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":84},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX01\"}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":85,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":93,\"X\":14,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":15,\"XX\":6},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":86,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":88,\"X\":14,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":14,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":92},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":87,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":54},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":89,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":90,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":91},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":94,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":95,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":96,\"X\":15,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":15,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":97,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":98,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":99},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":100,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":108,\"X\":16,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":17,\"XX\":6},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":101,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":103,\"X\":16,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":16,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":107},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":102,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":54},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":104,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":105,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":106},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":109,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":110,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":111,\"X\":17,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":17,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":112,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":113,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":114},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":115,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":123,\"X\":18,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":19,\"XX\":6},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":116,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":118,\"X\":18,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":18,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":122},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":117,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":54},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":119,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":120,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":121},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":124,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":125,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":126,\"X\":19,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":19,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":127,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":128,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":129},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX X=XX01;XX XX=XX;XX XX=XX;XX=XX11;XX XX XX=XX;\"}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":130,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":131,\"X\":20,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":20,\"XX\":13},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":132,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":133,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":134},\"XX\":\"XX\"}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":136,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":137,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":138,\"X\":22,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":22,\"XX\":88},\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":XX}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":139,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":143,\"X\":22,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":22,\"XX\":88},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":140,\"X\":138,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":142},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":141,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":137}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":144,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":145,\"XX\":\"XX_45321\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":217,\"X\":23,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":35,\"XX\":4},\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":146,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":150,\"X\":24,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":24,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":147,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":148,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":149},\"XX\":XX}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":151,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":152,\"XX\":\"XX_45322\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":203,\"X\":25,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":34,\"XX\":6},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":153,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":XX,\"X\":XX}],\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":154,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":161,\"X\":26,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":34,\"XX\":6},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":162,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":163,\"X\":27,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":34,\"XX\":7},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":164,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":202,\"X\":27,\"XX\":16,\"XX\":34,\"XX\":7},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":199,\"XXX\":\"XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":200,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":155,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":156,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":160,\"X\":26,\"XX\":12,\"XX\":26,\"XX\":27},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":157,\"XXX\":\"X.X\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":158,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":153},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":159,\"XXX\":\"X\"}}},\"XX\":XX}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":201,\"XXX\":\"XX\"}},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":165,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":166,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":194,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":33,\"XX\":39},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":196,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":197},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":198},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":167,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":191,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":33,\"XX\":30},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":188,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":189},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":193},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":168,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":186,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":31,\"XX\":69},\"XXX\":188,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":190},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":169,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":183,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":31,\"XX\":60},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":180,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":181},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":185},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":170,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":178,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":57},\"XXX\":180,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":182},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":171,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":175,\"X\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":48},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":173,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":174},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":177},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":172,\"XXX\":173,\"XX\":\"X \"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":176,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":179,\"XXX\":180,\"XX\":\"XX.X.XXX\\X  X XX=0,\\X   XXX=XX_X,\\X   XX=XX_XX(XX_X_X(XX(X,XX,XX_X))),\\X   XX=(X XX(*) XX XX XX \"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":184,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":187,\"XXX\":188,\"XX\":\"XX.X.X_XX)\\X  XX X='X_XX' \\X  X XX='\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":192,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":195,\"XXX\":196,\"XX\":\"XX.X.XX_X_XX_XX'\\X  \"}}}]}}],\"XX\":[155]}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":204,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":216,\"X\":35,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":35,\"XX\":130},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":205,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":207,\"X\":35,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":35,\"XX\":130},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":215},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":206,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":137},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":208,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":214,\"X\":35,\"XX\":89,\"XX\":35,\"XX\":130},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":213,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":209,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":210,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":40}},{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":211,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":212,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":152}}]}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":218,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":219,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":220,\"X\":37,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":37,\"XX\":64},\"XXX\":\"XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":XX}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":221,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":225,\"X\":37,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":37,\"XX\":64},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":222,\"X\":220,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":224},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":223,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":219}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":226,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":227,\"XX\":\"XX_45323\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":304,\"X\":38,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":52,\"XX\":4},\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":228,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":232,\"X\":39,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":39,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":229,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":230,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":231},\"XX\":XX}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":233,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":234,\"XX\":\"XX_45324\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":275,\"X\":40,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":47,\"XX\":6},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":235,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":XX,\"X\":XX}],\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":236,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":243,\"X\":41,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":47,\"XX\":6},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":244,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":245,\"X\":42,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":47,\"XX\":7},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":246,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":274,\"X\":42,\"XX\":16,\"XX\":47,\"XX\":7},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":271,\"XXX\":\"XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":272,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":237,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":238,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":242,\"X\":41,\"XX\":12,\"XX\":41,\"XX\":27},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":239,\"XXX\":\"X.X\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":240,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":235},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":241,\"XXX\":\"X\"}}},\"XX\":XX}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":273,\"XXX\":\"XX\"}},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":247,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":248,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":266,\"X\":42,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":43,\"XX\":59},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":268,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":269},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":270},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":249,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":263,\"X\":42,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":43,\"XX\":50},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":260,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":261},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":265},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":250,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":258,\"X\":42,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":42,\"XX\":61},\"XXX\":260,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":262},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":251,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":255,\"X\":42,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":42,\"XX\":52},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":253,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":254},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":257},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":252,\"XXX\":253,\"XX\":\"XX XX \"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":256,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":259,\"XXX\":260,\"XX\":\"XX.X.X_XX XX X\\X   XX (X XX X_XX XX \"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":264,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":267,\"XXX\":268,\"XX\":\"XX.X.XX_X_XX_XX  XX X_XX XX X XX) XX X\\X    XX X.XX = X.X_XX\\X  XX X XX XX\\X   X (XX) X (X.X_XX);\\X  \"}}}]}}],\"YYYYYYYY\":[237]}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":276,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":288,\"X\":48,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":48,\"XX\":106},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":277,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":279,\"X\":48,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":48,\"XX\":106},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":287},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":278,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":219},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":280,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":286,\"X\":48,\"XX\":65,\"XX\":48,\"XX\":106},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":285,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":281,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":282,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":40}},{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":283,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":284,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":234}}]}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":289,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":292,\"X\":50,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":52,\"XX\":4},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":290,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":291,\"X\":50,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":50,\"XX\":31}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":293,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":294,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":297,\"X\":51,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":52,\"XX\":4},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":295,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":296,\"X\":51,\"XX\":10,\"XX\":51,\"XX\":69}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":298,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":299,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":303,\"X\":52,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":52,\"XX\":102},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":300,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":302,\"X\":52,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":52,\"XX\":102},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":301,\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_X_X_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":145}}}]}}]}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":305,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":306,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":307,\"X\":53,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":53,\"XX\":59},\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":XX}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":308,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":312,\"X\":53,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":53,\"XX\":59},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":309,\"X\":307,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":311},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":310,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":306}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":313,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":314,\"XX\":\"XX_45325\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":391,\"X\":54,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":67,\"XX\":4},\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":315,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":319,\"X\":55,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":55,\"XX\":16},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":316,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":317,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":318},\"XX\":XX}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":320,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":321,\"XX\":\"XX_45326\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":362,\"X\":56,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":62,\"XX\":6},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":322,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":XX,\"X\":XX}],\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":323,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":330,\"X\":57,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":62,\"XX\":6},\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.X\",\"XX\":331,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":332,\"X\":58,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":62,\"XX\":7},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":333,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":361,\"X\":58,\"XX\":16,\"XX\":62,\"XX\":7},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":358,\"XXX\":\"XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":359,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":324,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":325,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":329,\"X\":57,\"XX\":12,\"XX\":57,\"XX\":27},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":326,\"XXX\":\"X.X\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":327,\"XXX\":\"X\",\"XX\":322},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":328,\"XXX\":\"X\"}}},\"XX\":XX}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":360,\"XXX\":\"XX\"}},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":334,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":335,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":353,\"X\":58,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":61,\"XX\":39},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":355,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":356},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":357},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":336,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":350,\"X\":58,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":61,\"XX\":30},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":347,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":348},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":352},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":337,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":345,\"X\":58,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":58,\"XX\":58},\"XXX\":347,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":349},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":338,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":342,\"X\":58,\"XX\":27,\"XX\":58,\"XX\":49},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":340,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":341},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":344},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":339,\"XXX\":340,\"XX\":\"X  \"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":343,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":346,\"XXX\":347,\"XX\":\"XX.X.XXX\\X  X XX=1,XX=XX_X \\X  XX X='X_XX' \\X  X XX='\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":351,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":354,\"XXX\":355,\"XX\":\"XX.X.XX_X_XX_XX'\\X  \"}}}]}}],\"XX\":[324]}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":363,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":375,\"X\":63,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":63,\"XX\":101},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":364,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":366,\"X\":63,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":63,\"XX\":101},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":374},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":365,\"XXX\":\"XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":306},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":367,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":373,\"X\":63,\"XX\":60,\"XX\":63,\"XX\":101},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":372,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":368,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":369,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":40}},{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":370,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":371,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":321}}]}}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":376,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":379,\"X\":65,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":67,\"XX\":4},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":377,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":378,\"X\":65,\"XX\":8,\"XX\":65,\"XX\":31}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":380,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":381,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":384,\"X\":66,\"XX\":7,\"XX\":67,\"XX\":4},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":382,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":383,\"X\":66,\"XX\":10,\"XX\":66,\"XX\":64}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":385,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":386,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":390,\"X\":67,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":67,\"XX\":78},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":387,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":389,\"X\":67,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":67,\"XX\":78},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":388,\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_XX_X_XX_XX__X_XX\",\"XX\":227}}}]}}]}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XXXX\",\"XX\":392,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":393,\"XX\":\"XX_45327\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":399,\"X\":68,\"XX\":9,\"XX\":69,\"XX\":4},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":394,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":398,\"X\":69,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":69,\"XX\":69},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":395,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":397,\"X\":69,\"XX\":5,\"XX\":69,\"XX\":69},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":396,\"XXX\":\"X_XX_X_X_XX_XX_XX_XX_X_XX\",\"XX\":314}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":400,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":410,\"X\":70,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":70,\"XX\":25},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":401,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":409,\"X\":70,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":70,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":406,\"XXX\":\"XX.X\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":407,\"XXX\":\"XX\"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":408,\"XXX\":\"X\"}},\"X\":[{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":402,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":403,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":405,\"X\":70,\"XX\":15,\"XX\":70,\"XX\":24},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":404,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":393}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":411,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":417,\"X\":71,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":71,\"XX\":25},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":412,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":416,\"X\":71,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":71,\"XX\":25},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XXX\",\"XX\":413,\"XXX\":\"XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":414,\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":40},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":415,\"XXX\":\"XX\"}}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":419,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":420,\"XX\":\"XX_45328\",\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":426,\"X\":74,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":75,\"XX\":2},\"XXX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":421,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":425,\"X\":75,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":75,\"XX\":55},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":422,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":424,\"X\":75,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":75,\"XX\":55},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":423,\"XXX\":\"X_XX___X_XX_X_XX_XX\",\"XX\":15}}}]}},{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":427,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.X\",\"XX\":428,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":429,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":437,\"X\":77,\"XX\":1,\"XX\":78,\"XX\":2},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":430,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":432,\"X\":77,\"XX\":4,\"XX\":77,\"XX\":17},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\"},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":436},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":431,\"XXX\":\"__XX__\"},\"X\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":433,\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":434,\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":435},\"XX\":\"XX\"},\"XX\":\"__XX__\"}},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":438,\"XX\":[{\"XX\":\".X.XX\",\"XX\":439,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":443,\"X\":78,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":78,\"XX\":9},\"XX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":440,\"X\":{\"XX\":\".X.XXX\",\"XX\":442,\"X\":78,\"XX\":3,\"XX\":78,\"XX\":9},\"XXX\":{\"XX\":\".XX.XX\",\"XX\":441,\"XX\":\"XX\",\"XX\":420}}}]}}]}}]}}]}</data>\n"
            + "</xmi:XMI>\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                sb.append(' ');
                SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
                MySaxParser.MyHandler handler = new MyHandler(i);
                InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(input.replace("AAA", sb.toString())));
                saxParser.parse(is, handler);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error disappears if I change the XML version to 1.0 or replace the parser from the Java runtime (I tested with Java 8, 11 and 15) with the parser from Apache Xerces.

Is this a (maybe known) issue in the SAXParser that comes with the Java runtime? Or is it necessary to escape `{, }, [, ]` in XML version 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a bug in the `XML11DocumentScannerImpl` class. The `scanContent` method of the `XMLDocumentScannerImpl` class is overridden and the overriding method does not reset the length of a temporary string after processing it. In most cases, this has no effect, but if the input buffer is refreshed in such a situation while processing character data, the content of this temporary string is appended to the buffer again, resulting in the observed wrong behaviour. So the occurrence of the bug depends on size of the input (must not fit into a single input buffer) and the offset (must be inside character data) and it may depend on `']'` in the character data too.

I reported the bug to the openjdk project.